# Declare Swift "let" constant with 32-bit and 64-bit platforms

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, 32bit-64bit

I found a mistake in a function project. 
This function convert decimal value to binary string. 
I would convert again to decimal but I have crash in 32Bit processor (iPhone5C) but it's working in 64Bit processor (Iphone5S) :

```
let valueDInBinary = valueBinary[valueBinary.index(valueBinary.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)...valueBinary.index(valueBinary.startIndex, offsetBy: 18)]

let valueD = Int(valueDInBinary, radix: 2)
```

If I choose offset less than 8 binary number, I don't have a crash on 32Bit processor. 
Is-it problem of Constant Value 'Let' with maximal value ? As Int32 ?

How I can convert large binary number to decimal ?

Thanks you !

Paul

Comment: What is the crash error?

Comment: What is the content of `valueDInBinary` on the 5c and 5s?

Comment: Use `Int64` or `UInt64` ...

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup error is : Thread1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT,subcode=Oxe7ffdefe)

Comment: @kennytym valueDinBinary contains my binary value : 01010101010101010101

Comment: @MartinR : I can't use Int64 for a iPhone5C deployment because it implemented with 32bit processor

Comment: You *can* use Int64 on a 32-bit processor.

Comment: @Martin R : How my Int on 32bit processor can hold value more than +2,147,483,647 ?

Comment: `Int64` is a 64-bit integer, even on a 32-bit processor. Why don't you just try it?